# Derivative of operator $\mathcal{A} : C(I) \rightarrow C(I)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b$ and $I = [a,b]$ be a closed interval. Further let $C(I)$ be the vector space of continuous real valued functions on $I$ with the norm $\vert \vert x \vert \vert_\infty$. Let $k \in C(I \times I)$ and for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define the operator $\mathcal{A} : C(I) \rightarrow C(I)$ by

$$\mathcal{A}f(x) = \int_I k(x,y) f^n(y) dy.$$

I would like to compute the derivative $\mathcal{A}'f(0)$ at $0$. My attempt was starting from the definition of the derivative, thus I should be able to do something like

$$\mathcal{A}f(x) = \mathcal{A}(0)(x) + L(f(x)-0) + R(f(x)) \vert \vert f(x)-0 \vert \vert_\infty,$$
and after rearrangement I get
$$L(1) = \frac{\mathcal{A}f(x)-\mathcal{A}(0)(x)}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert_\infty} - R(x)$$
$$
= \frac{\int_I k(x,y) 0^n(y) dy - \int_I k(x,y) 0^n(y) dy}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert_\infty} -R(x)=
 \frac{\int_I (k(x,y)-k(x,y)) 0^n(y) dy}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert_\infty} - R(x).$$

Is this correct so far? I have some trouble to proceed at this point. I also would like to compute the derivatives for some other points, but first I would like to check if I am on the right track. Thank you for guidance in advance!

Comment: Do you want to compute the derivative of $x\mapsto \mathcal A f(x)$ or the derivative of $f\mapsto \mathcal Af$ ? (I guess you want to compute the second one, but it's not super clear from your attempt)

Comment: Ah, I think it was also not very clear on my exercise sheet. I would like to compute the later one. Thus I made a mistake, I guess. It should not be at the point zero, but at the zero function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that $\mathcal A$ is Fréchet differentiable on $C(I)$ with Fréchet derivative at $f$ given by :
$$\mathcal A'_f : g\in C(I) \mapsto \left[x\mapsto\int_I k(x,y) nf^{n-1}(y)g(y)\ dy\right] $$

To see it, we will simply apply the definition of the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) at $f$ of $\mathcal A$ : For any non-zero $h\in C(I)$, we have
$$\begin{align}\mathcal A(f + h)(x) - \mathcal A f(x) &=\int_I k(x,y) (f(y) + h(y))^n\ dy - \int_I k(x,y) f^n(y)\ dy\\
&=\int_I k(x,y)\left[(f(y) + h(y))^n - f(y)^n\right]\ dy\end{align} $$

Hence we have
$$\begin{align}\left\|\mathcal A(f+h) - \mathcal A f - \mathcal A'_f(h) \right\|_\infty &= \sup_{x\in I} \left|\int_I k(x,y)\left[(f(y) + h(y))^n - f(y)^n - nf(y)^{n-1}h(y)\right]\ dy\right|\\
&\le \sup_{x\in I}\int_I |k(x,y)||(f(y) + h(y))^n - f(y)^n - nf(y)^{n-1}h(y)|\ dy \\
&\le \|k\|_\infty \int_I |(f(y) + h(y))^n - f(y)^n - nf(y)^{n-1}h(y)|\ dy \tag1 \\
&= \|k\|_\infty \int_I |n\mu(y)^{n-1}h(y) - nf(y)^{n-1}h(y)|\ dy \tag2 \\
&= \|k\|_\infty \int_I |h(y)||n\mu(y)^{n-1} - nf(y)^{n-1}|\ dy \\
&\le n\|k\|_\infty \|h\|_\infty \int_I |\mu(y)^{n-1} - f(y)^{n-1}|\ dy
\end{align}$$

In the above, I used in equation $(1)$ that $k$ is a continuous function over a compact set hence has finite sup-norm $\|k\|_\infty$, and in equation $(2)$ I applied the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to the function $\varphi :t \mapsto t^n$ between the points $b = f(y) + h(y) $ and $a = f(y) $, which tells us that there exists a point $c\equiv \mu(y)$ in the open interval $]a,b[$ such that
$$\varphi(b)-\varphi(a) = \varphi'(c) (b-a) \iff (f(y) + h(y))^n - f(y)^n = n\mu(y)^{n-1}h(y)$$
For some $\mu(y)\in]f(y),f(y) + h(y)[$ (order may need to be swapped depending on the sign of $h(y)$).

Now, notice that for $\|h\|_\infty\to0$, we have that $h(y)\to 0$ for all $y\in I$ by definition, which implies that $|\mu(y)-f(y)| \to 0$ for all $y\in I$ as well. By continuity of $t\mapsto t^{n-1}$, this implies that $|\mu(y)^{n-1}-f(y)^{n-1}| \to 0$ for all $y\in I$.

Finally, we can conclude by the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) that
$$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{\|h\|_\infty\to 0}\frac{\left\|\mathcal A(f+h) - \mathcal A f - \mathcal A'_f(h) \right\|_\infty}{\|h\|_\infty} &\le \lim\limits_{\|h\|_\infty\to 0}n\|k\|_\infty \int_I |\mu(y)^{n-1} - f(y)^{n-1}|\ dy\\
&= n\|k\|_\infty \int_I \lim\limits_{\|h\|_\infty\to 0}|\mu(y)^{n-1} - f(y)^{n-1}|\ dy\\
&= 0
\end{align} $$

As desired.

Also note that by using essentially the same argument, you can prove that the Fréchet derivative of any operator of the form
$$\mathcal{T}f(x) = \int_I k(x,y) \varphi(y,f(y))\ dy $$
For some continuously differentiable function $\varphi$ is given by
$$\mathcal{T}'_fg(x) = \int_I k(x,y) \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial f}(y,f(y)) g(y)\ dy $$